# Transform rational equations to polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

I have a list of rational equations and I would like to convert it to a list of polynomial equations. I know that none of the variables and none of the denominators could ever be 0. 
So far I have tried:

```
removeDenom[ a_ == b_ ] := Numerator[a]Denominator[b] == Numerator[b]Denominator[a];

ratToPol[eqn_] := removeDenom @* Together @ eqn;
```

Which seems to do the trick for rational equations with small exponents of the variables but for larger ones, e.g.

```
x[1]^24566482 x[2]^25894864 x[3]^36056313 x[5]^2 x[6]^2==(x[1]^10050244 x[2]^10878704 x[3]^15147675 x[6]^8)/x[5]^4+x[1]^39374641 x[2]^41453905 x[3]^57720898 x[5]^4 x[6]^2 x[7]^2
```

I get the error General::lrgexp Exponent is out of bounds for function `1`.

Any ideas on how to proceed? It would be nice if there was a way without using Simplify or other higher-level functions for which it is unknown how they operate exactly.

Comment: Could use `Numerator[Together[expressionList]]`.though this too will balk at large exponents.

Comment: How about `0 == (eqn /. Equal -> Subtract /. x[i_]^(j_ /; j > 0) -> x[i, j] // 
     Together // Numerator) /. x[i_, j_] -> x[i]^j ` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ratToPol[eqn_Equal] := Module[
  {prod = Times @@ Cases[eqn, t_ :> Denominator[t], 2]},
  Assuming[prod != 0, MultiplySides[eqn, prod] //
    Simplify]]

eqn = x[1]^24566482 x[2]^25894864 x[3]^36056313 x[5]^2 x[
      6]^2 ==
   (x[1]^10050244 x[2]^10878704 x[3]^15147675 x[6]^8)/
     x[5]^4 + 
    x[1]^39374641 x[2]^41453905 x[3]^57720898 x[5]^4 x[6]^2 x[7]^2;

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]

eqn2 = ratToPol@eqn
```

[image]

```
Simplify[Or @@ Thread[(List @@ eqn2[[1]]) == 0]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This function works for the example expression

```
removeDenom[a_ == b_] := Block[{
   u = Times @@ Denominator /@ a,
   v = Times @@ Denominator /@ b},
  Expand[u a v] == Expand[u b v]
  ]
```

It multiplies the LHS by all the denominators it finds on the RHS and vice versa.

The `polynomialGCD` error occurs in `Together`, so don't use `ratToPol`.  Just use `removeDenom[p]`

Also, `removeDenom` does NOT play nice with subscripted variables `u` and `v`, but it seems to work with `x`.

Comment: Expand has the same problems. Also the code doesn't work: removeDenom[x + y - z + 1 == 1/x] returns 4+4x+4y-4z == 4/x :/ This because mapping Denominator on a sum gives the sum of the denominators. An alternative implementation using List@@ would be removedenom[a_ == b_] := With[{eq = a - b},
  #[[1]]==#[[2]]&[ Times @@ Denominator[List @@ (eq + 1)]*# & /@ eq ]
] but then the result is unexpanded and indeed: Expand returns Expand::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function Expand. (although not consistently...)